# Processing a list of json strings in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to transform the input I get with spark streaming in order to create a dataframe out of it. Basically I receive a list of json strings from which I would want to extract the data.

Note: I reduced the json strings to just the coords objects which should be sufficient for the general concept.

**The input I get:**

> ["{\"coord\":{\"lon\":10.0217,\"lat\":53.5281}}", "{\"coord\":{"lon\":10.1169,\"lat\":53.6522}}", "{\"coord\":...."]

**The dataframe I want to create in order to save it to a database:**

```
+----------+----------+
|lon       |lat       |
+----------+----------+
|   10.0217|   53.5281|
|   10.1169|   53.6522|
|   ...    |   ...    |
+----------+----------+
```

So far I managed to replace the excaped quotes which leaves me with a array of strings.
I tried to flatten the array:

```
result = df \
            .selectExpr("Cast(value AS STRING) as json") \
            .withColumn("json", f.regexp_replace('json', '\\\\"', '"')) \
            .withColumn("json", f.flatten(f.col("json"))) \
            .select("json")
```

Error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'flatten(`json`)'
> due to data type mismatch: The argument should be an array of arrays,
> but '`json`' is of string type.;;

Then I tried to load the array with `json.loads`, but I was not able to call this function from Spark streaming.

**So how do I extract the data from this input?**

Comment: It looks like you are missing a backslash before the `lon`, is this correct?

Comment: @BrendanA Corrected it. I missed it when double escaping it for stackoverflow. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

With the array provided

```
arr = [
    "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":10.0217,\"lat\":53.5281}}", 
    "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":10.1169,\"lat\":53.6522}}", 
    ]
```

You can get the desired result with the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions, types

df = (df.withColumn("lon", functions.regexp_extract("value", "(?<=lon\"\:)[0-9]+.[0-9]+", 0))
        .withColumn("lat", functions.regexp_extract("value", "(?<=lat\"\:)[0-9]+.[0-9]+", 0)))

df = df.select(df["lon"], df["lat"])

df.show()
+-------+-------+
|    lon|    lat|
+-------+-------+
|10.0217|53.5281|
|10.1169|53.6522|
+-------+-------+
```